# Stackoverflowerror while running Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, stack-overflow

Attempted to Javadoc my group's App project, but got stackoverflowerror.  Tried increasing heap space, but that did not seem to help.  I've googled this question, but all I've seen are questions and answers about apps that use recursion.  Anybody else encountered this problem with Javadoc? More to the point, does anybody know why Javadoc would do this?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a StackOverflowError, increasing the Heap space does not help at all, as you don't have a "HeapOverflowError" (usually manifested as OutOfMemoryError).

Increase the stack size instead, use the `-Xss` VM option (i.e. passed with `-J...` before all other options and arguments).

Note that normally a stack overflow error is a sign of a bug in the program, which would be Javadoc in your case. Try a newer version of the JDK, if you don't do already.